# Experiences using Groovy++ in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, groovy++

has anybody tried to implement a Grails solution having Groovy++ under the hood ?

Comment: THere's a groovy++ plugin for grails now http://code.google.com/p/groovypptest/downloads/list?saved=1&ts=1282375860

Comment: You might want to change the accepted answer on this, see edits to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Groovy++ uses Groovy 1.7.5 and contains plugin integrating G++ with Grails

Answer (score 2):

<strike>It won't currently work.</strike>

Grails 1.3.2 (the current latest) uses Groovy 1.7.3

Groovy++ requires Groovy 1.8 (which is currently unreleased)

[Please see Alex's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171749/experiences-using-groovy-in-grails/4399781#4399781http://)  instead of this one...