# Does Groovy++ work with Grails 2.0

Tags: grails-2.0, groovy++

I have performance problems in Grails 2.0.  I'm wondering if groovy++ will help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can currently use Groovy++ with Grails 2.x ([docs](http://code.google.com/p/groovypptest/wiki/GrailsIntegration)).

A better approach would be to look where the problems are. Then determine a strategy to solve them. Randomly swapping out libraries or tools is unlikely to help. What kind of performance problems do you have (speed, memory usage)? Do you use some kind of logging or a profiler to see where in your application it is spending the most time?

Comment: FWIW this question seems to indicate that there are some Groovy++ options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171749/experiences-using-groovy-in-grails?rq=1

Comment: For Groovy 1.7 and 1.8, yes. Grails 2.x depends on Groovy 2.0, afaik.